# Passed Array Mismatch

Tags: arrays, vba, mismatch

I'm having problems with an array after passing it into a function. Basically I'm passing an array which contains a series of strings that I want to check against some know values. When I try and do this I get the mismatch error.

I tried to diagnose the problem with the msgbox but this has confused me further as when running the code the message box pops up and shows the string the in the array. Then when I click OK the msgbox command apparently errors with a mismatch fault even though it has just displayed the correct infomation. Can anyone tell me why there would be a mismatch?

**Error:**
[image: Error]

**Code:**

```
Public Function A2LConvert(ByRef Software As Variant) As Variant

For i = 0 To 6
MsgBox (Software(i))
    If Software(i) = "A" Then 'Or "A1" Then
        A2LConvert(i) = "A.txt"
    ElseIf Software(i) = "C" Then
        A2LConvert(i) = "C.txt"
    ElseIf Software(i) = "B" Then
        A2LConvert(i) = "B.txt"
    ElseIf Software(i) = "D" Then
        A2LConvert(i) = "D.txt"
    ElseIf Software(i) = "E" Then
        A2LConvert(i) = "E.txt"
    ElseIf Software(i) = "F" Then
        A2LConvert(i) = "F.txt"
    ElseIf Software(i) = "G" Then
        A2LConvert(i) = "G.txt"
    Else
        A2LConvert(i) = ""
    End If

Next i

End Function
```

Comment: How are you passing the value to the function?

Comment: It's really unclear what you are trying to do. My Guess is that you want to replace the values directly in the passed  array, however what you are doing is recalling your function with the new value (`x.txt`). No sense. It is accepted at that point because `software` is declared as `variant` and thus your function accepts anything (reason why always working with variants is a bad habbit). The whole logic seems wrong, and the semantic isn't good either: you should use `select case` instead of all your `elseif`. Describe clearly what you want to achieve and I'll provide you with the right code.

Comment: also TAG your question with the proper MS Office product: Excel or Accces or other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a condition is met for the first time, your conditional expression is recalling the function A2LConvert, however it is passing variant i (initially 0).

For example,

```
    A2LConvert(i) = ...
```

is actually making a function call to A2LConvert and passing 0 as the 'Software' variant. It then attempts to access the zeroth property of 0 in that msgbox call, which triggers the type mismatch error.

The behaviour that (I think) you want can be achieved by implementing an intermediary array (tempAr):

```
Public Function A2LConvert(ByRef Software As Variant) As Variant

Dim tempAr(6) As Variant

For i = 0 To 6
MsgBox Software(i)
    If Software(i) = "A" Then 'Or "A1" Then
        tempAr(i) = "A.txt"
    ElseIf Software(i) = "C" Then
        tempAr(i) = "C.txt"
    ElseIf Software(i) = "B" Then
        tempAr(i) = "B.txt"
    ElseIf Software(i) = "D" Then
        tempAr(i) = "D.txt"
    ElseIf Software(i) = "E" Then
        tempAr(i) = "E.txt"
    ElseIf Software(i) = "F" Then
        tempAr(i) = "F.txt"
    ElseIf Software(i) = "G" Then
        tempAr(i) = "G.txt"
    Else
        tempAr(i) = ""
    End If

Next i

A2LConvert = tempAr

End Function
```

Comment: This has solved it. I understand why this has happened now, Thanks!